# Can I get an item's repository path in subversion without being connected to vpn?

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I can access my subversion repository only when I am on the Client's VPN connection, because the repository is there.

But, frequently, I only need to get access to the path of an item in a folder and connecting to VPN frequently wastes a lot of time.

Is there any way, I can get the path without connecting to the VPN and hence without connecting to the repository?

Comment: the only way that I can think of that you could access data in the repository without connecting to it is if you kept a local copy.

Comment: I have a local working copy folder with me, I need to get an item's url without connecting

Comment: well wouldn't it just be the same IP address/domain and repository name each time? the path is what's changing, and if you have a local copy then you have the directory structure right there to draw the path from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the element in a working copy you can use [svn info /path/to/element/in/working/copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html). The line beginning with `URL:` contains the URL of the element. This shouldn't need a connection to the repository.